# How to select outermost '#document' in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, salesforce

I'm trying to add a class to the body like so:

```
const body = document.querySelector('body');
body.classList.add('someClass');
```

The problem is that I have another '#document' in an iframe that also has body element in it. So it adds the exact same class in it also. How do I select the outer most #document and only append the class to the body element in that document?

I tried looking at the difference in the classList by doing this:

```
if (body.classList.contains('somethingThatShouldntBeThere')) {
   body.classList.add('someClass');
}
```

That didn't work. It seems like the javascript adds the class to ALL bodies in the DOM. Any ideas?

PS. And please note it's on a Salesforce page, I'm injecting this javascript. So I have no control over the initial code.

Comment: `It seems like the javascript adds the class to ALL bodies in the DOM` It shouldn't - `querySelector` will only ever select a single element. Maybe your JS is running both in the iframe and in the parent page, resulting in both being changed?

Comment: This rather sounds like the script runs on both pages. `querySelector` will only select the first element it finds.

Comment: Hmm, yeah this code is running in the chrome extension.That must be it, it's not like it's querySelectorAll

Comment: Try wrapping your code inside `if (parent === null) { ... }`, that way it shouldn't run on the page in the iframe.

Comment: ooh, that's a good idea. Let me try that.

Comment: Well, I couldn't find the answer, so I had to remove the class after.